# JSON response from ektorp / couchdb

Tags: json, couchdb, ektorp

For client requests to ektorp / couchdb I would like to pass JSON back to the client.
(Why not use couchdb direktly? Because I have to do some tweeks to the data on a Java layer inbetween.)

So is there for example a way to get JSON data from a CouchDbRepositorySupport queryView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
InputStream is = db.queryForStream(query);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode json = mapper.readTree(is);
```

(JsonNode and ObjectMapper are from the `org.codehaus.jackson` library.)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, from consulting the [documentation](http://ektorp.org/reference_documentation.html#d100e941) the following should do it

```
ViewResult result = db.queryView(query);
    for (ViewResult.Row row : result) {
       JsonNode docNode = row.getDocAsNode();

     }
```